# What's the difference between the call/return protocol of oldstyle and newstyle coroutines in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, generator, coroutine

I'm transitioning from old-style coroutines (where 'yield' returns a value supplied by 'send', but
which are otherwise essentially generators) to new-style coroutines with 'async def' and 'await'.
There are a couple of things that really puzzle me.

Consider the following old-style coroutine that computes the running average of numbers supplied to
it by 'send', at each point returning the mean-so-far. (This example is from Chapter 16 of *Fluent
Python* by Luciano Ramalho.)

```
def averager():
    total = 0.0
    count = 0
    average = None
    while True:
         term = yield average
         total += term
         count += 1
         average = total/count
```

If I now create and prime a coroutine object, I can send it numbers and it will return the running
average:

```
>>> coro_avg = averager()
>>> next(coro_avg)
>>> coro_avg.send(10)
10.0
>>> coro_avg.send(30)
20.0
>>> coro_avg.send(5)
15.0
```

...and so forth. The question is, how would such a coroutine be written with async/await? There
are three points that confuse me. Do I understand them correctly?

1) In the old style, anybody can send numbers to the same instance of the averager. I can pass
around the value coro_avg above and every time .send(N) is called, no matter from where, N is added to the same running
total. With async/await, however, there's no way to "send in a value". Each time you 'await' a
coroutine you await a new instance with its own context, its own variable values.

2) It seems that the only way for an 'async def' coroutine to hand a value back to the thing awaiting
it is to 'return' and hence lose context. You can't call 'yield' from inside an 'async
def' coroutine (or rather if you do you've created an async generator which
can't be used with await). So an 'async def' coroutine can't compute a value and hand
it out while maintaining context, as averager does.

3) Almost the same as (1): When a coroutine calls 'await' it waits for a single, specific awaitable,
namely the argument to await. This is very unlike old-style coroutines, which give up control and
sit around waiting for *anyone* to send something to them.

I realize that the new coroutines are a distinct coding paradigm from the old ones: They're used
with event loops, and you use data structures like queues to have the coroutine emit a value without
returning and losing context. It's kind of unfortunate and somewhat confusing that new and old share the same
name---coroutine---given that their call/return protocols are so different.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and perhaps instructive, to relate the two models pretty directly.  Modern coroutines are actually implemented, like the old, in terms of the (generalized) iterator protocol.  The difference is that return values from the iterator are automatically propagated upwards through any number of coroutine callers (via an implicit `yield from`), whereas actual return values are packaged into `StopIteration` exceptions.

The purpose of this choreography is to inform the driver (the presumed “event loop”) of the conditions under which a coroutine may be resumed.  That driver may resume the coroutine from an unrelated stack frame and may send data back into the execution—via the awaited object, since it is the only channel known to the driver—again, much as `send` communicates transparently through a `yield from`.

An example of such bidirectional communication:

```
class Send:
  def __call__(self,x): self.value=x
  def __await__(self):
    yield self  # same object for awaiter and driver
    raise StopIteration(self.value)

async def add(x):
  return await Send()+x

def plus(a,b):  # a driver
  c=add(b)
  # Equivalent to next(c.__await__())
  c.send(None)(a)
  try: c.send(None)
  except StopIteration as si: return si.value
  raise RuntimeError("Didn't resume/finish")
```

A real driver would of course decide to call the result of `send` only after recognizing it as a `Send`.

Practically speaking, you don’t want to drive modern coroutines yourself; they are syntax optimized for exactly the opposite approach.  It would, however, be straightforward to use a queue to handle one direction of the communication (as you already noted):

```
async def avg(q):
  n=s=0
  while True:
    x=await q.get()
    if x is None: break
    n+=1; s+=x
    yield s/n

async def test():
  q=asyncio.Queue()
  i=iter([10,30,5])
  await q.put(next(i))
  async for a in avg(q):
    print(a)
    await q.put(next(i,None))
```

Providing values that way is a bit painful, but it’s easy if they’re coming from another `Queue` or so.