# Why is it that only asynchronous functions can yield in asynchronous code?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, yield

In the article ["I'm not feeling the async pressure"](https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2020/1/1/async-pressure/) Armin Ronacher makes the following observation:

> In threaded code any function can yield. In async code only async functions can. This means for instance that the writer.write method cannot block.

This observation is made with reference to the following code sample:

```
from asyncio import start_server, run

async def on_client_connected(reader, writer):
    while True:
        data = await reader.readline()
        if not data:
            break
        writer.write(data)

async def server():
    srv = await start_server(on_client_connected, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
    async with srv:
        await srv.serve_forever()

run(server())
```

I do not understand this comment. Specifically:

- How come synchronous functions cannot `yield` when inside of asynchronous functions?
- What does `yield` have to do with blocking execution? Why is it that a function that cannot `yield`, cannot block?

Comment: Do you understand what "yield" means in the context of that article?

Comment: Perhaps not. Is he not using the word "yield" in the sense of the `yield` keyword, e.g. a generator iterator?

Comment: Nope. It means letting other code run.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Perhaps you could write a short answer pointing out the meaning of yield, so that the question is resolved?

Comment: @user4815162342 Based on the helpful comment by Harvey and some extended thinking/reading, I wrote an extended answer myself. Hopefully it sounds correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going line-by-line:

> In threaded code any function can yield.

Programs running on a machine are organized in terms of *processes*. Each process may have one or more *threads*. Threads, like processes, are scheduled by (and interruptible by) the operating system. The word "yield" in this context means "letting other code run". When work is split between multiple threads, functions "yield" easily: the operating system suspends the code running in one thread, runs some code in a different thread, suspends that, comes back, and works some more on the first thread, and so on. By switching between threads in this way, concurrency is achieved.

In this execution model, whether the code being suspended is synchronous or asynchronous does not matter. The code *within* the thread is being run line-by-line, so the fundamental assumption of a synchronous function---that no changes occurred in between running one line of code and the next---is not violated.

> In async code only async functions can.

"Async code" in this context means a single-threaded application that does the same work as the multi-threaded application, except that it achieves concurrency by using asynchronous functions *within* a thread, instead of splitting the work *between* different threads. In this execution model, your interpreter, not the operating system, is responsible for switching between functions as needed to achieve concurrency.

In this execution model, it is unsafe for work to be suspended in the middle of a synchronous function that's located inside of an asynchronous function. Doing so would mean running some other code in the middle of running your synchronous function, breaking the "line-by-line" assumption made by the synchronous function.

As a result, the interpreter will wait only suspend the execution of an asynchronous function in between synchronous sub-functions, never within one. This is what is meant by the statement that synchronous functions in async code cannot yield: once a synchronous function starts running, it must complete.

> This means for instance that the writer.write method cannot block.

The `writer.write` method is synchronous, and hence, when run in an async program, uninterruptible. If this method were to block, it would block not just the asynchronous function it is running inside of, but the entire program. That would be bad. `writer.write` avoids blocking the program by writing to a write buffer instead and returning immediately.

Strictly speaking, `writer.write` *can* block, it's just inadvisable to do so.

If you need to block inside of an async function, the proper way to do so is to `await` another async function. This is what e.g. `await writer.drain()` does. This will block asynchronously: while this specific function remains blocked, it will correctly yield to other functions that can run.

Answer (score 1):

“Yield” here refers to [cooperative multitasking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking) (albeit within a process rather than among them).  In the context of the `async`/`await` style of Python programming, asynchronous functions are [defined in terms of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900306/8586227) Python’s pre-existing generator support: if a function blocks (typically for I/O), all its **callers** that are performing `await`s suspend (with an invisible `yield`/`yield from` that is indeed of the generator variety).  The actual call for any generator is to its `next` method; that function actually **returns**.

**Every** caller, up to some sort of driver that most programmers never write, must participate for this approach to work: any function that did not suspend would suddenly have the responsibility of the driver of deciding what to do next while waiting on the function it called to complete.  This “infectious” aspect of asynchronicity has been called a [“color”](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/); it can be problematic, as for example when people forget to `await` a coroutine call that **looks** correct because it looks like any other call.  (The `async`/`await` syntax exists to minimize the disruption of the program’s **structure** from the concurrency by implicitly converting functions into state machines, but this ambiguity remains.)  It can also be a good thing: an asynchronous function can be interrupted exactly when it `await`s, so it’s **straightforward** to reason about the consistency of data structures.

A synchronous function therefore cannot yield simply as a matter of **definition**.  The import of the restriction is rather that a function called with a normal (synchronous) **call** cannot yield: its caller is not prepared to handle such an interaction.  (What will happen if it does anyway is of course the same “forgotten `await`”.)  This also affects **refactoring**: a function cannot be changed to be asynchronous without changing all its clients (and making them asynchronous as well if they are not already).  (This is similar to how *all* I/O works in Haskell, since it affects the **type** of any function that performs any.)

Note that `yield` is **allowed** in its role as a normal generator used with an ordinary `for` even in an asynchronous function, but that’s just the general fact that the caller must expect the same *protocol* as the callee: if an enhanced generator (an “old-style” coroutine) is used with `for`, it just gets `None` from every `(yield)`, and if an `async` function is used with `for`, it produces awaitables that probably break when *they* are sent `None`.

The distinction with threading, or with so-called *stackful* coroutines or **fibers**, is that no special resumption support is needed from the caller because the actual function call simply **doesn’t return** until the thread/fiber is resumed.  (In the thread case, the kernel also chooses *when* to resume it.)  In that sense, these approaches are easier to use, but with fibers the ability to “sneak” a pause into any function is partially compromised by the need to specify **arguments** to that function to tell it about the userspace scheduler with which to register itself (unless you’re willing to use global variables for that…).  Threads, on the other hand, have even higher **overhead** than fibers, which matters when great numbers of them are running.